# How i can use permissionplugin with zxing nuget pkg in xamarin.forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, zxing

**OnRequestPermissionsResult mentioned in permissionplugin pkg by** "jamesmontemagno"

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

**OnRequestPermissionsResult mentioned in Zxing pkg**

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
            {

                global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            }
```

**I am trying to achieve it using the following code.**

```
[Activity(Label = "BarcodeScanning", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait | ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }       
    }
```

I want to use both Nuget Packages and show users to show the popup for location permission.
Please provide me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting permissions is an OS requirement and has nothing to do with ZXing or any library in general.

Now if you check the [PermissionsPlugin's](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) Github you will find all your answers there

[Current Activity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) plugin is a must-have for this package to work properly, Also always add the needed permissions into the `info.plist` for iOS.

Then you ask for permission something like this:

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<LocationPermission>();
```

You can check the available API's [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#api-usage) and a simple example can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#in-action)

Comment: I followed the "PermissionsPlugin" document and already used in my previous projects but when I removed: global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
scanning stop working. so my issue is how to "OnRequestPermissionsResult" for both the libraries.

Comment: Why do you even want to remove it in the first place?